# How to disable multiple radio buttons with sequential ids?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to disable all the radio buttons; the best approach is by using javascript but i am not too good at it; I try looping the ids but it was a disaster!
i end up using 6 lines to disable each radio button at a time; can I do this a little more efficiently

```js
document.getElementById("radio1").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("radio2").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("radio3").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("radio4").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("radio5").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("radio6").disabled = true;
```

```html
Radio Buttons:<br>
<input type="radio" id="radio1">1<br>
<input type="radio" id="radio2">2<br>
<input type="radio" id="radio3">3<br>
<input type="radio" id="radio4" checked>4<br>
<input type="radio" id="radio5">5<br>
<input type="radio" id="radio6">6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` to select all inputs with `type="radio"` and then use loop to set `disabled = true` on each one

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].disabled = 'true';
}
```

```html
Radio Buttons:
<br>
<input type="radio" id="radio1">1<br>
<input type="radio" id="radio2">2<br>
<input type="radio" id="radio3">3<br>
<input type="radio" id="radio4" checked>4<br>
<input type="radio" id="radio5">5<br>
<input type="radio" id="radio6">6
```

Comment: this will disable any other input element on the page

Comment: Yes fixed that so now it will only select `input[type="radio"]`

Comment: That is good to know; just in case I have to add more input requests!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why looping was a disaster. Here's how I would do it:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    document.getElementById("radio" + i).disabled = true;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
var ids = ['radio1', 'radio2', 'radio3', 'radio4', 'radio5', 'radio6'];

ids.forEach(function (id) {
    document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css selector (document.querySelectorAll):

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='radio']"); //get all elements that have an id starting with 'radio'
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    radios[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along these lines

```
// load all the inputs in the document into memory
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

// loop over them, and set the disabled attribute on each of them
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {    
    inputs[i].disabled = true; 
}
```

Note that by doing `document.getElementsByTagName("input")`, you collect **all** the inputs in your page, so a better approach would be to wrap them in a container, and do the expression on it, like this:

```
<div id="input-container">
   <input type="radio" id="radio1">
   ...
</div>
```

and then

```
var container = document.getElementById("input-container");
var inputs = container.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

the loop remains the same